# Python Take raw input and search for it in a line with multiple characters

Tags: python

I'm trying to search for a specific set of characters, user defined, in a string at a specific point. This is my code so far:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
f = open("text.txt", 'r')
linelist = f.readlines()
f.close

User_number = raw_input('What number would you like to single 
out from your text?')
anum1 = User_number[0]
anum2 = User_number[1]

f4 = open("Modded_text.txt", "w")

for line in linelist:
    i =0;
    if anum1 in line[10] and anum2 in line[11]:
        f4.write(line)
f4.close()
```

The problem I have is that this gives me "IndexError: string index out of range". It also seems to be a messy way of doing what I want even if it did work. Can anyone advise me on how I can get this working and improve my code?

Comment: Your code isn't complete. What is `Atom_number`? Also can you edit into your post the full error traceback?

Comment: add if len(line)>11:  before your if. And btw, what is i?

Comment: Fair point FHTMitchell. I've edited the question to be correct.

Comment: How to improve your code? Get it working, then post it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted your traceback, but I am guessing your out-of-range error is happening here:

```
if anum1 in line[10] and anum2 in line[11]:
```

and that is because the code assumes every line in the file is at least 12 characters long. You probably have a blank line in your input file, most likely at the end, which is zero characters long. Do away with this line: `i =0;` (it isn't doing anything useful) and in its place put:

```
if len(line) < 12:
    continue
```

That will guarantee that the data is in line with your code's expectations.